# Store Icon Uri in Class or Ressource

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, resources, icons, windows-phone

I want to store the URIs of my application bar icons in a central place. There are some options for this but I'm not sure what's the right one is:

- public class with static attributes

  ```
  public class AppBarIcons
  {
      public static Uri PlayIcon = new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/play.png", UriKind.Relative);
  }
  ```
- public class with static attributes and get-method

  ```
  public class AppBarIcons
  {
      public static Uri PlayIcon 
      {
          get { return new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/play.png", UriKind.Relative); }
      } 
  }
  ```
- A resource file like AppResources for localized strings

Answer (score 0):

Static attributes will be more difficult to maintain over time. For this reason I recommend using the AppResources and using your static attributes with the get-method to read the KeyValue pairs from settings. This way if your settings need to be modified from /Assets to /OtherAssets you can change one file rather than going through each class.